# Randomized Quick Sort and Partition Probability?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, computer-science, integer-partitions, sorting

We know about [Quick Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) and [Randomized Version](https://alg12.wikischolars.columbia.edu/file/view/QUICKSORT.pdf) and Partition. I ran into a Fact when I read my notes.

Let $0 < a < 0.5$ be some constant. We have an $n$-element array as input. Randomized quicksort chooses one element from array uniformly at random as a pivot and partitions. With probability $1-2a$ the smallest section be greater than $an$.

How this probability is calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the probability that the smaller of the two sections contains more than fraction $a$ of the array.

If the pivot element is selected uniformly at random from the array, then one section will contain fraction $X$ of the array, and the other will contain fraction $1-X$, where $X$ has uniform distribution over the interval $[0,1]$. So the desired probability is
$$P(\min(X,1-X)>a)$$
which has probability $1-2a$ because 
$$\min(X,1-X)>a\ \Longleftrightarrow\ a<X<1-a\;.$$